# Display float with variable spaces in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to display float number like this:

```c
0.64        0           1    
0.64        0.0625      1    
0.64        0.125       1    
0.64        0.1875      1    
0.64        0.25        1    
0.64        0.3125      2    
0.64        0.375       2    
0.64        0.4375      2    
0.64        0.5         2
```

i know that i need to use %g but how can the spaces change ?
thanks

Comment: add "\t" for tab

Comment: @Ora That's not going to work when the length of the shortest printed number is 8 or more chars less than the length of the longest printed number.

Comment: Try the format specifier `%12g`, or to ensure a space afterwards, reduce the "width" part of the specifier by one and add an explicit space, like: `%11g %11g %d`.